# Issue with updating values in C# array within a WinForms PictureBox MouseMove event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a C# WinForms application where I'm handling the MouseMove event of a PictureBox. I'm attempting to update certain values in an array (temp) based on the mouse movement and then use these updated values in a subsequent operation.

However, I'm encountering a problem where temp[3] and temp[4] always seem to revert to 0 despite my attempts to update them. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm managing the array within the event handler.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouse = true;
            last = e.Location;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouse = false;
        }
        private Point last;
        private DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.X < 333)
            {
                treeView1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                treeView1.Visible = false;
                if (e.X > this.Width - 50 && e.Y > this.Height - 100)
                {
                    label1.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            if (mouse)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - dateTime).TotalMilliseconds > 100)
                {
                    dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    string[] temp = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Name.Split(',');
                    temp[3] = ((int.Parse(temp[3]) + e.X - last.X) / 10).ToString();
                    temp[4] = ((int.Parse(temp[4]) + e.Y - last.Y) / 10).ToString();
                    last = e.Location;
                    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Name = string.Join(',', temp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Or rather a problem with math?  You seem to calculate the difference of the last movement in between of 2 MouseMove calls and then take a tenth of it? The diff should be small to begin with. Mostly smaller then 10. And something smaller then 10 divided by 10 is 0.

Comment: The normal code was without division by 10. I added 10 because it was moving too much.